# Check Address Before Sending

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm writing a macro that looks at the recipient's address and if a certain name then show a vbYesNo msgbox. However it shows me the msgbox when sending to myself (Aaron Islam).

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next
' use lower case for the address
' LCase converts all addresses in the To field to lower case
RecipientsName = Item.Recipients

If RecipientsName = "Sarah Bloggs" Or "Sarah Smith" Then

    If InStr(LCase(Item.To), "Sarah Smith" Or "Sarah Weedon") Then
        Prompt$ = "You sending this to " & Item.To & ". Is it the correct one?"
        If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

Else: Exit Sub

End If       

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove On Error Resume Next. Errors will generate so you can fix them. Especially when debugging it should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use On Error code until you know how. Errors are hidden so you cannot fix them.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim Prompt As String

    ' LCase converts strings to lower case 
    If InStr(LCase(Item.To), LCase("Sarah")) Then
        Prompt = "You are sending this to " & Item.To & ". Is it the correct one?"
        If MsgBox(Prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code for getting the recipients name works correctly:

Not sure why you have two if statements to check the content.

However, in both you need to use the `OR` like this:

```
If RecipientsName = "Sarah Bloggs" Or RecipientsName =  "Sarah Smith" Then
```

You always have to write the full condition like:

```
If value1 = value2 [AND/OR value3=valu4] ...
```

Read more about the VBA If...Then...Else statement on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/752y8abs.aspx